# jquery - get div from a li

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, z-index

I am new in javascript/jquery. 
I am trying to select from a `li` element a `div` in wich i will put 3 images. So I have this variable:

```
var x = ui.item.parent().children()[i]
```

Which is the `li` (it works, i've check the id), but how can I get the div from `x` ? (and after that all 3 images so i can change the `z-index` of the images, which i also don't know how).

```
<ul>
   <li id="li1">
   <div>
       <img class="1" src="img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;z-index=1">
       <img class="2" src="img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;z-index=2">
       <img class="3" src="img3.jpg" style="position:absolute;z-index=3">
   </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is the code i write, but is not working (error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'find' )

```
for(var i=0;i<ui.item.parent().children().length-4;i++){
    var x =ui.item.parent().children()[i];
    x.find('img').css('z-index', '2');  
                }
```

Comment: `$(x).closest("div")`?

Comment: As Liam said, your HTML is malformed. You have tags opening and closing in the wrong order.

Comment: please correct your html

Comment: You could use from your child: x.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0], or you directly access the images by: x.getElementsByTagName('IMG') which is a collection of all the images.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your html. Your ul ends before you li does.
Once you have a jQuery element, you can use the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to search its childs.

For example:

```
var x = $('li#yourid');

x.find('img').css('z-index', '2');
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find'

Comment: @user2440433 Probably because you aren't passing the listelement to the jQuery function

Comment: I do not have the li id, and i dont want to work with id for li, i just put the id for checking if it works to get the li form the list.

Comment: for(var i=0;i<ui.item.parent().children().length-4;i++){
    var x =ui.item.parent().children()[i];
    x.find('img').css('z-index', '2'); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

your HTML is not valid, you're closing the `li` tag after the `ul` and the `li` do not have the open tag `<`.

So correct HTML is:

```
<ul>
<li id="li1">
<div>
<img class="1" src="...">
<img class="2">
<img class="3">
</div>
</li>
<ul>
```

Now to get the div from x you need to use `.find()`:

```
var div = x.find('div');
```

Comment: Find is not working: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find'

Comment: if your `var x` is valid it should work. Remember that `.find()` is a jQuery method so you need to load it before your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$("ul li").children("div").find("img").each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heNx8/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that HTML is just an example, but it's not correctly formatted. It should be:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li1">
        <div>
            <img class="1" src="..."/>
            <img class="2"/>
            <img class="3"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To set the z-index: $(x).find('img').css('z-index','100');

Comment: find dos not work, the html is just for example, i can put the html but is too big.

Comment: what if i have 3 images, how do i select the secound one?